# Process multiple request from different threads in batches on one processing thread

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have a system that uses multiple threads to process data. These data could be processed individually but it would be better to process them in batches.

Lets assume we have a class `Data`, a class `OtherData` and a class `Processor` which implements `Function<List<Data>, List<OtherData>>`.

To process objects of type `Data` from multiple threads I designed two classes `System` and `Evaluator`.

```java
public class System {
    private final Evaluator evalThread;
    private final Object sync = new Object();
    private Function<List<Data>, List<OtherData>> processor;
    private Map<Object, Data> inputMap;
    private Map<Object, CompletableFuture<OtherData>> futureMap;
    private List<Object> idList;

    public System() {
        processor = new Processor();
        inputMap = new HashMap<>();
        futureMap = new HashMap<>();
        idList = new LinkedList<>();

        evalThread = new Evaluator(processor, inputMap, futureMap, idList, sync);
        Thread thread = new Thread(evalThread, "EvalThread");
        thread.start();
    }

    public CompletableFuture<OtherData> process(Data data) {
        Object id = new Object();

        final CompletableFuture<OtherData> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

        synchronized (sync) {
            inputMap.put(id, data);
            futureMap.put(id, completableFuture);
            idList.add(id);

            if (idList.size() >= 32) {
                sync.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        return completableFuture;
    }
}

public class Evaluator implements Runnable {
    private final Function<List<Data>, List<OtherData>> processor;
    private final Map<Object, Data> inputMap;
    private final Map<Object, CompletableFuture<OtherData>> futureMap;
    private final List<Object> idList;
    private final Object sync;

    private AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public Evaluator(Function<List<Data>, List<OtherData>> processor, Map<Object, Data> inputMap, Map<Object,
                      CompletableFuture<OtherData>> futureMap, List<Object> idList, Object sync) {
        this.processor = processor;
        this.inputMap = inputMap;
        this.futureMap = futureMap;
        this.idList = idList;
        this.sync = sync;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (sync) {
            while(keepRunning.get()) {
                if (idList.size() > 0) {
                    List<Data> input = new LinkedList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
                        input.add(inputMap.get(idList.get(i)));
                    }

                    List<OtherData> output = processor.apply(input);

                    for (int i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
                        futureMap.get(idList.get(i)).complete(output.get(i));
                    }

                    idList.clear();
                    inputMap.clear();
                    futureMap.clear();
                }

                try {
                    sync.wait(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was that any one can call `process` with singular data but the data will (if there are enough) be processed together with other `Data` objects.

Any suggestions for improvements or are there systems in the Java-framework that would fit this task better?
Do you might see problems according to deadlocks, etc.?

Comment: Can you explain the motivation for batching these tasks? If I read this correctly, you're running batches of 32, no more or less regardless of the request timing, which seems weird to me.

Comment: That is not correct. If an call to `process` insertes the 32th element to be processed. The eveluation thread wil be awoken to process all scheduled data and then will call `sync.wait(20)`. So if in the next 20ms under 32 elements got scheduled, the thread will nontheless be awoken and process the scheduled data.

Comment: I think I understand it now. Still, can you talk about _why_ the tasks are better batched?

Comment: Perhaps use Runnable instead of Thread

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter the data gets processed by an neuralnet which can faster evaluate multiple data at once compare to processing each data item on it own

Comment: @PPann the `Evaluator`-Class is an `Runnable` or what is it what you are suggesting

Comment: @Ackdari, yes, looks to me a better fit? what do you think?

Comment: @PPann like I said, it _is_ a `Runnable`, so what change are you suggesting?

Comment: I might not understand but your code seems overly complicated for what it does.  If all you need to do is process elements every 20ms, then every 20ms dump the data processor into an `Executor` or `ExecutorService`.  Seems like most of the complication goes away at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically you should really post complete code and not have
missing definitions.  Especially since `Data` and `OtherData` could
instead be generic type arguments perhaps, or interfaces, so that it's
actually clear what's happening.  I'm just gonna imagine they're
basically both `Object`s.  Also `Processor` is undefined.  If it was
really not important just pass it in as an argument to `System`, as it
is, this is incomplete too.

---

In `System` having a separate `idList` is pointless, the `inputMap`
already has the right size for implementing back pressure (I wanted to find a good definition, but right now at least Wikipedia doesn't have one under that term; basically if the input can grow unlimited, the system might not be able to catch up if processing takes too long and you might end up with a congested (read: out of memory) system).

---

In `Evaluator`, `x.size() > 0` could be `!x.isEmpty()`, that might
potentially be cheaper, but it also expresses intent a bit more clearly:
The check is really whether the map "isn't empty", not about how many
items are in the container exactly.

`InterruptedException` is for control flow,
[don't just print a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java).

Also now that I read it, why's there three containers, `inputMap`,
`futureMap` and `idList` all related to the same task?  It'd be much
easier if there was just a sequence of tuples, `Tuple<Input, Future>`,
and then work through them.  Then replace the `List` with a
[`BlockingQueue<Tuple<Input, Future>>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and it's already supporting the
waiting / back pressure too.  An [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) could be used to
limit the number of elements, while a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) could have
an unbounded size (that's really not advisable though).

Lastly instead of `keepRunning` a tombstone object could then be
inserted to cancel the thread, then there's also no need for polling via
`wait`.  That is, insert a `new Tuple<>()` (same as the IDs at the
moment via `new Object()`) and when dequeuing from the input, check
whether this element was inserted, due to the object identity being
unique that's then safe to do.

So without spelling it all out, the main thread would look like this
perhaps:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Tuple<Input, Future> tuple = input.take();
        if (tuple == tombstone) {
            return;
        }
        tuple.getFuture().complete(processor.apply(tuple.getInput()));
    }
}
```

With some implementation of `Tuple` of course; a custom class would work
too.

---

For the other questions:  I can't see it deadlocking right now, the check for 32 and the `notifyAll` are a bit odd though.

Other tools in the Java tool set?  Yes, I'd suggest starting with reading through the [`java.util.concurrent` namespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).  In particular the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CyclicBarrier` with only the neural-net thread waiting, and decrement it after adding an item to the queue (which should probably be a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`). Then it will automatically trigger after every 32 entries, at which point it should pop exactly 32 entries from the head of the queue (an operation that won't block if it's the queue's only consumer).

You can probably eliminate the `synchronized` block in `process` if you also replace both `HashMap` instances with `ConcurrentHashMap`. This will improve performance when `process` is called from more than a small constant number of threads (probably on the order of 2 or 3).